# Understanding Delegate Command in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm struggling to understand the usage of delegate commands (from Prism) and I build a dummmy application in which I intend to do the following.

I have the command as

```
private readonly DelegateCommand selectAll;

public ICommand SelectAll
{
    get { return selectAll; }
}
```

and use it as

```
selectAll= new DelegateCommand(SelectAll,CanSelectAll);

private bool CanSelectAll()
{
   if (AllSelectedItems.Count()>3)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

```
public IList<Student> AllItemsSelected
{
    get => m_Items;
    set => Set(ref m_Items, value);
}
```

I can see the button being disabled as expected when my ViewModel gets initialized but after even though sometimes this `AllSelectedItems.count > 3`, it doesn't seem to update and notify the UI.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You may have to call `selectAll.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` after setting m_Items.

Comment: Which `DelegateCommand`is this? Prism? Telerik?

Comment: Prism..........

Comment: @Clemens would really appreciate an example if you could, struggling here for a while now

Comment: Please consider aligning the property and method names in your code. The name `SelectAll` is duplicated for the property and the execute method and there is an incosistent use of `AllSelectedItems` and `AllItemsSelected`. You can also simplify your `CanSelectAll` method like this: `return AllSelectedItems.Count()>3`, no need for an `if` with boolean `return`s, that is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CanSelectAll` method is not called automatically when the collection changes, after all how should the command know when to reevaluate the the condition? You have to explicitly tell it to do so.

An `ICommand` exposes a [`CanExecutChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged?view=net-6.0) event that must be raised to notify the element binding the command to call the [`CanExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute?view=net-6.0) method in order to evaluate if the command can be executed or not. This usually enables or disables the element in the UI, e.g. a `Button`. When and how this event is raised depends on the concrete implementation of the `ICommand` interface.

In Prism for `DelegateCommand`s, this can be done in two different ways.

- Call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on the command. This could be done in the setter of your `AllItemsSelected` property.

  ```
  public IList<Student> AllItemsSelected
  {
      get => m_Items;
      set 
      {
         Set(ref m_Items, value);
         selectAll.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
      }
  }
  ```
- Another way of doing this is using the [`ObservesProperty`](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/commanding.html#observesproperty) method when instantiating the command. You pass a lambda for the property to be observed and the command will automatically raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event once a [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-6.0) event is raised for it. That means this mechanism only works if your view model implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-6.0) and your property raises `PropertyChanged`.

  ```
  selectAll= new DelegateCommand(SelectAll, CanSelectAll).ObservesProperty(() => AllItemsSelected);
  ```

Which mechanism you choose is up to you. For your specific case it is important to know how `AllItemsSelected` changes. If you always assign a new collection once the selection changes, the examples above will work, since then each time the setter of the property is called and `PropertyChanged` is raised and therefore `ObservesProperty` will pick up the change and call `CanExecutChanged` for example.

However, if you reuse the same collection, e.g. only add and delete items from it, this will not work, as the actual collection object does not change, which means no call to the setter and no `PropertyChanged`. In this case put the call to `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` into the method that adds, deletes or modifies the collection.

---

In case the collection is modified somewhere else e.g. items are added through the UI directly to the collection, you would have to use a collection type that supports notifying collection changes like `ObservableCollection<T>` (through the [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-6.0) event). You could add a handler to `CollectionChanged` which calls `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`.

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
   private readonly DelegateCommand _selectAll;

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      _selectAll = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSelectAll, CanExecuteSelectAll);
      AllSelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
      AllSelectedItems.CollectionChanged += OnAllSelectedItemsChanged;
   }

   public ICommand SelectAll => _selectAll;

   public ObservableCollection<Student> AllSelectedItems
   {
      get => m_Items;
      set => Set(ref m_Items, value);
   }

   private void ExecuteSelectAll()
   {
      // ...your code.
   }

   private bool CanExecuteSelectAll()
   {
      return AllSelectedItems.Count > 3;
   }

   private void OnAllSelectedItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      _selectAll.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very well explained, insightful answer. For anyone coming here in the future I was able to also get a good understanding from this video - https://youtu.be/tYItSPv58Bo

Answer (score 1):

When you create the command, tell it to observe the property  `AllItemsSelected`, like this:

```
selectAll= new DelegateCommand(SelectAll,CanSelectAll)
                         .ObservesProperty(() => AllItemsSelected);
```

That will make the command's state update every time `AllItemsSelected` changes.

This function, `ObservesProperty` is a nice feature of Prism.   It lets you set up one-time monitoring of all your properties on which that comand's state depends.